# How to change the bar colors of a chart in a crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

How to change the bar colors of a chart in a crystal report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In design view, right-click on the bar you want to change and click Format Series Riser.
In the available options, change the color to the desired value. As far as I know you can't change the bar color programatically. The .Net sdk provides minimal ability for accessing chart objects. Using Chart Object you can only set properties such as Height, Width, Border, etc., at runtime and retrieve information about the Chart Object in a report.

[image]

Comment: I can't do this coz I don't have the full version. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of. See revised answer.